# I would like to evaluate the exponential function e^x on a series of sums

Tags: python

Following from a different question where I had to use a for loop to calculate the sums, I was only able to print one of the numbers. But if the end total of numbers in the series went up to 1000, it would not calculate.

Here's the question:

[image]

I received some other assistance on this part of the code. It's correct, but I would like it to print the other two sums as well, the one where it goes up from 1000 to 10000. Thanks!

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 100+1):
    sum += ((-1)**(i+1))/i
print(sum)
```

Then I needed to evaluate the exponential function `e^x` on each of the sums individually, but I can't go further from 100. Here's my other part of code:

```
!pip install mpmath
from mpmath import *
import math

sum = 100
sum2 = 1000
sum3 = 10000

print(math.exp(sum))
print(math.exp(sum2))
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: The sums aren‘t equal to 100, 1000, and 10000, though. And I have no problem running your first code snippet with 100 replaced with 1000 or 10000, so what does ”it would not calculate” mean?

Comment: I can only see the answer to the 100, not to a bigger digit like 1000 or 10000.

Comment: And when you can’t see the answer, it‘s because… there’s an error? Which error?

Comment: Ah, there's no error, I think I haven't added the line of code to print it because I'm unsure. New to python...

Comment: You have code that works for 100, right? When you replace 100 with 10000 and change nothing else, does it stop working? If so, can you add a screenshot of that to your question?

Answer (score -2):

you can do it very easily without using the mpmath module.

```
sum = 100
sum2 = 1000
sum3 = 10000
for[i=1,i>0,i++]:
    print(sum**i)
```

if you want exponent to be limited to a certain number, just do

```
x=-your-exponent-number
for[i=1,i<x,i++]:
    print(sum**i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I'm coding in Python. Could you alter the code a little please? Thanks!